# Table carregada por javascript passando tags

Tags: javascript, ajax

Eu tenho uma `table` que é carregada via `ajax`, desta forma:

```
 $.each(data.listaNSerie, function (i, item) {
                $("#tableNSerie").append("<tr>"
                    + "<td>" + item.produto.codigo + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + item.produto.nome + "</td>"
                    + "<td type='text' class='form-control'>" + "</td>"
                    + "</tr>");
            });
```

Funciona, e eu recebo os dados via `controller`, porém quando o usuário pressiona enter, pois na terceira coluna é digitável, e é passada para o `controller`, ele recebe assim: `265656/2<div>26626262626 /&nbsp; 26262626</div>`, sendo que ele deveria receber assim: `265656/226626262626/26262626`, como resolver ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, tirando a parte html, com o método abaixo:

```
 public static string StripHTML(string input)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
    }
```